# Can I get a passport using expired state ID?

Tags: passport-renewals

Will my expired ID Card work? I also have an expired passport to show and have birth certificate with state seal and SS card.

Comment: I'm guessing for USA, is that correct?

Comment: How long ago did your expired passport expire?

Comment: You probably need only expired passport to get the new one.

Comment: Reply to Midavalo-YES

Comment: reply to mlc 1 year 2 months ago

Comment: reply to anish yes use old passport to get a new one but I need another form of identity  state ID that is expired

Comment: mlc my ID expired 1 yr 2mo ago my passport expired in 2005

Answer (score 4):

The DoS [states](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/need-passport/apply-in-person.html) :

> > Your evidence must be an original or certified, physical copy. A certified copy is any document that has the seal or stamp of the
> > official issuing authority. You must submit one of the following
> > documents:
>
> - Full validity, undamaged U.S. passport (expired passports are accepted). Full validity means the document is/was valid for 10 years
>   for adults and 5 years for children under 16.
> - U.S. birth certificate that meets the following requirements:
>   Issued by the city, county, or state of birth
>   Lists your full name date of birth, and place of birth
>   Lists your parent(s)' full names
>   Has the date filed with registrar's office (must be within one year of birth)
>   Has the registrar's signature
>   Has the seal of the issuing authority
> - Consular Report of Birth Abroad or Certification of Birth
> - Certificate of Naturalization
> - Certificate of Citizenship

A State ID is not a citizenship proof of any means (99% of them don't even state your citizenship, this is excepted Enhanced DLs, but while they are valid for travel, they aren't a citizenship proof)

You can submit either your expired passport or your Birth Certificate

From @Dimitry Vulis in the comments :

> Afditionally, if you're eligible to renew by mail using form [DS-82](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/have-passport/renew.html) - it's easy, and your old expired passport is all you need. But if the old passport was issued >15 years ago , use DS-11 and apply in person.

Comment: Thanks I will apply in person

Answer (score 2):

For the requirement to present ID, the [adult US passport apply-in-person page](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/need-passport/apply-in-person.html), "Present ID" section, says:

> You must present one of the following identification documents (IDs)
> to the acceptance agent. The ID must readily identify you.
>
> - Valid or expired, undamaged U.S. passport book or passport card
> - In-state, fully valid driver's license or enhanced driver's license with photo
> - Certificate of Naturalization
> - Certificate of Citizenship
> - Government employee ID (city, county, state, or federal)
> - U.S. military or military dependent ID
> - Current (valid) foreign passport
> - Matricula Consular (Mexican Consular ID) - commonly used by a parent of a U.S. citizen child applicant
> - U.S. Permanent Resident Card (Green Card) - commonly used by a parent of a U.S. citizen child applicant
> - Trusted Traveler IDs (including valid Global Entry, FAST, SENTRI, and NEXUS cards)
> - Enhanced Tribal Cards and Native American tribal photo IDs
> - Note: you may be asked to present an additional ID when presenting one of these three documents: 1) In-state, fully-valid learner's
>   permit with photo, 2) In-state, fully-valid non-driver ID with photo,
>   or 3) temporary driver's license with photo.
>
> If you cannot present one of the IDs above, or for more information,
> please see Identification.

As you can see, if you present a state driver's license or state ID, it needs to be valid. However, one of the acceptable items is a valid or expired US passport. Since you have an expired US passport, that should be sufficient for the ID requirement.

Comment: This is only to identify you in-person, you still need to submit a proof of citizenship, which DLs aren't

Comment: @NicolasFormichella but expired passports are.  In this case the applicant will be relying on the expired passport as both proof of citizenship and proof of identity.  What's the point of mentioning the driver's license here?

Comment: Sorry ID, and yes indeed @phoog