# Can I apply for a new US passport using only my expired US passport?

Tags: usa, passports

According to this [website about applying in person,](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/need-passport/apply-in-person.html), it lists the documents needed to be shown during the application. In both categories of present ID and proof of citizenship, it says an expired passport is valid. However, it doesn't say if I can bring my expired passport for both categories, or if it would only fulfill one of the requirements. Can I bring only my expired passport or do I need to supplement it with another document for the category it doesn't fulfill?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/181155

Comment: If your passport is less than five years expired, you may find it more convenient to [renew by mail](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/have-passport/renew.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I bring only my expired passport or do I need to supplement it with another document for the category it doesn't fulfill?

Since expired passports are accepted in both cases, you only need to bring your expired passport

---

> [U.S. Passports - Apply in Person - U.S. Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/need-passport/apply-in-person.html)
>
> - **2. Provide Evidence of U.S. Citizenship**
>   You must submit **one** of the following documents:
>
>   - Full validity, undamaged U.S. passport (**expired passports are accepted**). Full validity means the document is/was valid for 10 years for adults and 5 years for children under 16.
>     ...
> - **3. Bring a Photocopy of U.S. Citizenship Evidence**
>   ...
> - **4. Present ID**
>   You must present **one** of the following identification documents
>
>   - Valid or **expired**, undamaged U.S. passport book or passport card
>     ...